# Android Instagram native app "Couldn't refresh feed" when opening private posts

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram

I am creating an app where I am required to open a post in the native instagram app using in general the following code:

```
Intent instagram = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse(post.getPostUrl()));
//post.getPostUrl() returns strings such as https://instagram.com/p/5mL0S1pZmR/
instagram.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
startActivity(instagram);
```

This works fine for public posts, however, if the poster of the image has their account set to private, the Instagram app activity contents are blank and a `Toast` with the message

```
Couldn't refresh feed
```

is shown.

I am logged into the Instagram native app, and also am following the private users for which I test this issue (posters of the private images). I have tested this problem on a few different phones, and the result is the same, even if the account logged into the native app varies.

Any pointers for how I might get rid of this issue, for which I can find no solution on the web and StackOverflow?

Please help, I would be very grateful for any tips!